# Read input text file

Tags: fortran90

I am finding difficult to read the text file assign the values for respective variables as soon in code.Please help me, Thank you

```
Program Console2
IMPLICIT NONE
Real :: BB,CC,DD
Integer n,AA
Character (LEN=8) Line
OPEN(UNIT=2,FILE="Chaq.txt",STATUS='unknown')
Do  n=1,10
READ (2,('(a6,I12,F8.2,F8.2,F8.2)'))Line,AA,BB,CC,DD
write (*,*) AA,BB,CC,DD
End Do
End  program Console2
```

Input File is

```
 GRID        3954        -182.53196.65596-28.5831                           
 GRID        3955        -186.40268.61172-28.5831                           
 GRID        3957        -187.65493.24453-28.5831                           
 GRID        3958        -173.982108.158 -28.5831                           
 GRID        3959        -166.58396.77976-28.5831                           
 GRID        3960        -164.51897.80294-28.5831                           
 GRID        3961        -194.53573.86154-28.5831                           
 GRID        3962        -186.237101.5011-28.5831                           
 GRID        3963        -174.59296.25317-28.5831                           
 GRID        3965        -184.89788.38072-28.5831                           
 GRID        3966        -193.65277.39146-28.5831                           
 GRID        3967        -168.41599.97072-28.5831                           
 GRID        3968        -165.85866.80172-28.5831                           
 GRID        3970        -174.87381.45816-28.5831                           
 GRID        3971        -184.27268.54756-28.5831                           
 GRID        3972        -173.699100.7843-28.5831                           
 GRID        3973        -172.326102.0733-28.5831                           
 GRID        3974        -178.06985.87581-28.5831                           
 GRID        3975        -173.97666.80172-28.5831
```

Comment: What you have posted suggests that the data file contains entries such as `-182.53196.65596-28.5831` which do not easily parse as numbers.  Is this an artefact of your posting or a realistic representation of the data inside the file ?

Comment: Thank you, exactly it is same as I posted I want differentiate with the 8 spaces and assign.

Comment: those dont look like all f8.2 to me. can you show the expected results for lines 1 and 4?

Comment: following up on my comment, this is "ok" because the decimal request `.2` gets ignored when the input field has its own a decimal. Presumably in this data every field has a decimal point..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to take account of the spaces in the input file.  Try this modification of your `read` statement:

```
 READ (2,('(1x,a4,8x,I4,8x,f8.2,f8.2,f8.2)')) Line,AA,BB,CC,DD
```

Note the use of the `x` control edit descriptor, which tells the run-time how many character positions to ignore. Note also that I've understood your input file lines to start with one blank.

Comment: why its not working: 'READ (2,('(1x,a4,8x,I5,8x,f8.2,f8.2,f8.2)'))Line,AA,BB,CC,DD'

Comment: Thank you I got It,(7x,I5) Its running.Really I cleared my droughts and confusion thank you